# how to modify string arrays with scanner?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble finding how to modify characters from the scanner. The code should take a number like '9' and find it's place in the chart, switching it from an 'o' to say, an 'x.' My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class a10
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("1 for first class \n2 for economy \n3 to view seating chart \n0 to exit");

//error message: Your choice must be a number between 0 and 3.
int menu = input.nextInt();

if (menu == 1) {
System.out.println("Which seat would you like (1-9): ");
int selection = input.nextInt();
//Seats in first class must be between 1 and 9.");
}
else if (menu == 2) {
System.out.println("Which seat would you like (10-30): ");
int selection = input.nextInt();
//Seats in economy class must be between 10 and 30.");
}
else if (menu == 3) {
//public static boolean[] seatChart (boolean seatNumber)
char[] seatNumber;

char[][] grid = new char[][]{{'o','o','o'},{'o','o','o'},{'o','o','o'}};

      }
    }
 }
```

how it should look

```
Front
x x x
x x o
o o o
x x x
x x x
x x x
x o o
o o o
x o x
o o o
Back
```

Comment: *"How to proceed?"* Can you be a bit more thorough on exactly what the problem you're facing is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution :

```
static int ROWS = 10;
static  int COLS = 3;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

  System.out.println("1 for first class \n2 for economy \n3 to view seating chart \n0 to exit");

  boolean[][] grid = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];

  int menu = input.nextInt();

  if (menu < 3) {
      System.out.println("Which seat would you like " + (menu == 1 ? "(1-9)": "(10-30)")+": ");
      int selection = input.nextInt();
      if(((menu == 1 && selection <= 9 && selection >= 1) || (menu == 2 && selection <= 30 && selection >= 10))){
        grid[selection / 3][selection % 3] = true;
      }
  } else if (menu == 3) {

    for(int r = 0 ; r < ROWS; r++){
      for(int c =0; c < COLS ;c++){
        System.out.print(grid[r][c] ? 'x' : 'o');
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could get that error message (which you have in comments) by a conditional and throwing an error:

```
if (menu < 1 || menu > 3)
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("number not between 1 and 3");
```

This will kill the program. You could also change the effect of that if statement just to print something like 'please choose again.'

Next, I would argue that you actually don't need a double char array. You can print that chart with a for loop like this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < seatNumber.length; count++){
   System.out.print(seatNumber[count]+" ");
   if (count % 3 == 0) System.out.println();
}
```

So if you're referencing the seat numbers from left to right, this would probably be a good way to represent the seat chart.

Next, the `int selection` read in the case of 1 or 2 can access the `seatNumber` array simply by index. You can modify the char in this index to be x like this:

```
seatNumber[selection] = 'x';
```

Now, to start with an array which is all o's, you can use an array tool fill:

```
Arrays.fill(seatNumber, 'o');
```

You will need to `import java.util.Arrays` in order to do this at the top of the code. If you wish to avoid this, you can fill it with a for loop like this:

```
char[] seatNumber = new char[30];
for (int count = 0; count < seatNumber.length; count++){
   seatNumber[count] = 'o';
}
```

Also, you may want to write a while loop like `while(true){` around the code starting after you declare the `Scanner`. Then you can exit the program like this:

```
if (menu == 0) break;
```

This should allow you to fill in multiple seats and show the seating chart multiple times.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

loop through your Array keeping track of what number seat you are in.  When that number matches the seat chosen switch the value there to 'x'.

```
public char[][] takeSeat(char[][] grid, int seatNum) {
    int currentSeat = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < grid[i].length; x++) {
            currentSeat += 1;
            if(currentSeat == seatNum) {
                grid[i][x] = 'x';
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Also, I noticed you created your starting seat grid at option choice 3.  It would be better to have the char[][] created in the beginning of the code and keep updating it throughout the code so all you have to do at option 3 is display the chart.  To display the chart.  Example of how to display the chart:

```
else if (menu == 3) {
    //public static boolean[] seatChart (boolean seatNumber)
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < grid[i].length; x++) {
            System.out.print(grid[i][x]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Also wrap your option choices in a while loop so you can continuously run until the User selects 0.

Here is what your final code should end up looking like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    char[][] grid = new char[][]{{'o','o','o'},{'o','o','o'},{'o','o','o'}};
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("1 for first class \n2 for economy \n3 to view seating chart \n0 to exit");

        //error message: Your choice must be a number between 0 and 3.
        int menu = input.nextInt();

        if (menu == 1) {
            System.out.println("Which seat would you like (1-9): ");
            int seat = input.nextInt();
            if(!(seat < 1 || seat > 9)) {
                grid = takeSeat(grid, seat);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a valid seat number");
            }
            //Seats in first class must be between 1 and 9.");
        }
        else if (menu == 2) {
            System.out.println("Which seat would you like (10-30): ");
            int seat = input.nextInt();
            if(!(seat < 10 || seat > 30)) {
                grid = takeSeat(grid, seat);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a valid seat number");
            }
            //Seats in economy class must be between 10 and 30.");
        }
        else if (menu == 3) {
            //public static boolean[] seatChart (boolean seatNumber)
            for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < grid[i].length; x++) {
                    System.out.print(grid[i][x]);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        else if (menu == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid menu option, try again");
        }
    }
}

public static char[][] takeSeat(char[][] grid, int seatNum) {
    int currentSeat = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < grid[i].length; x++) {
            currentSeat += 1;
            if(currentSeat == seatNum) {
                grid[i][x] = 'x';
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return grid;
}
```